# Class greetings

Tags: greetings

I want to learn various greetings for the beginning of the class with my students. My class has expressed interest in Chinese. I'm looking for something like:

Good morning, dear seventh-grade class.
Good morning, Mr./Ms. ...

It would be nice if the students could use the phrase "Good morning, dear class" with few changes later to greet a group. It would be great if these phrases could be applied in a broad range of situations with as few pitfalls as possible. I would like to avoid the traditional "ni hao" Because they already know it.

I´ve come up with:
早安，亲爱的七年级同学们。
早上好， Klüßi。 同学们，欢迎回来
How bad is it?

Comment: As Tang Ho suggested, 亲爱的七年级 is not necessary, and frankly sounds stilted in this context. Just like you would not say, "Good morning, my dearest dad" every morning under normal circumstances? However, this 亲爱的.......级同学们 is Ok in certain formal settings where speeches are given in the school hall.

Answer (score 1):

> "Good morning, class" = "同学们，早上好"(Tóngxuémen, zǎoshang hǎo) or "早安，同学们"(zǎo ān, tóngxuémen)

You are in their classroom, they know what grade they are in

同学们 = students = class

> "Good morning, Mr./Ms...." = "老師，早上好" (Lǎoshī, zǎoshang hǎo) or "早安，老師" (zǎo ān, lǎoshī)

Your students only need to call you "老師", not "last name + 老師". They only refer to your last name to a third-party

> **同学们，你好** (Tóngxuémen, nǐ hǎo) = **Hello, class**

> **老師好** (Lǎoshī hǎo) = **Hello, teacher**

It is the more general greeting, you can use it in the morning, afternoon, or evening

> "好，課堂結束" (Hǎo, kètáng jiéshù) = Okay, class is over

> 再見，老師 (Zàijiàn, lǎoshī) = Goodbye, Teacher

Comment: There is a hidden message for "早安，亲爱的七年级同学们。" - "不是七年级的同学你們走錯教室了" :)

Comment: What explains "老師，早上好" & "早安，老師" being preferred over "老師，早安" & "早上好，老師"?

Comment: In Hong Kong, we say 先生早晨, never 早晨先生. because 先生 also means Mr. 早晨先生 could mean Mr. Morning.  But in Mardain, I think either way is acceptable